# Implementing custom versioning of a model minimising performance impact

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've got a Rails application set up and running just right in development mode. Its data model is quite simple, but has 3 of the models representing 90% of the whole data, which are:

- Model A: 3k records
- Model C: 1k records
- Model B: 45k records(which is a rich n to n association between the previous two)

I use MySQL, but probably going to switch to PostgreSQL in production.

All this data comes from external webservices in the form of JSON serialised Model A, with B and C nested inside. I've got a method that creates/updates them in my local database. The thing is, the webservice provides a VERSION parameter of this Model A, meaning every time that changes are made, it increases the version of the data it sends.

[image]

I don't support versioning from my side right now, and I'd like to be able to store as many versions of the data as the webservice gives me (checking every certain time). I'd like to be able to generate a version myself (from my backend) with changes I think need to be made.

I thought of adding a new boolean property in Model A (active), and duplicating Model A every time I get a new version. Model C is never versioned, so this operation will increase the number of records of Model A, and consequently Model B, as it'd need to duplicate all relationships to Model C.

[image]

This is fine so far but, considering I perform lots of statistical operations on Model C with varying criteria (regarding count of relations with model A, which is to count Model B), in this scenario I'd need to filter Model B by Model A's active property, which I can do with a JOIN statement, but I'm not sure if it will affect a lot to performance.

Another option is to popullate Model B with another active property whenever the active Model A is changed, but this sound like a really bad idea DB-wise, as it means duplicating data...

If I went for the first option, would it be a good idea putting a default scope in models A and B in Rails, so that I can "forget about" the data versioning? The default scope would filter by active, either in each model, or with a JOIN statement in Model B.

I might not be the best putting all this into words, but I'd really appreciate any help you're able to give me. I'll be checking the post so that I can clarify any doubts that may arise from my potentially poor explanation!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Instead of an "Active" flag, which will need a whole load of code, is the versioning an obvious linear pattern? If so just store whatever the version value is and scope your model to treat the latest version of your object as "Active".

Comment: I think you should check out the paper_trail gem if you haven't.

Comment: @Matt well, I didn't mention it for the sake of simplicity, but the data comes from 3 different webservices, so the version won't necessarily follow a linear pattern

Comment: @JoeEssey I did check Papertrail, but it seems to me it's more of an over-time version control, rather than an arbitrary one as I'm seeking here

Comment: @MartíGascó, I agree that's how it's most often used.  However, their readme states: "Allows you to get at every version, including the original, even once destroyed."  This will also solve the default scope problem and always represented the 'newest version.'